# Port not included in client-side OAuth flow

Tags: bug, api, authentication, oauth

I was recently making an app using the SE API's client-side auth flow. What I noticed is that there was this

> Unable to post message to http://localhost. Recipient has origin http://localhost:5000.

So after doing some debugging, I found that `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success` page, the script which notifies the original page that OAuth was successful has these lines:

```
    $(function () {
        var domain = 'http://localhost';
        var proxy = 'http://localhost:5000/static/proxy.html';
```

It looks like the 'domain' is incorrect (as it doesn't have the port), from what I can tell this looks like it is extracting it incorrectly from proxy.

I know that running my server on `:80` would fix this but it would be nice to not need to do that.

Comment: If you are using a nonstandard port, then you are using a server. You need to use the server-side (explicit) OAuth recipe for that, and [it does work](https://stackapps.com/questions/4596/can-the-redirect-uri-contain-port-number).